# How to find the contour of a blob using OpenCv + Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

#### Goal

I want to use [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) in Python to **find the precise contour** of the *blob*, but **ignore all the *tentacles*** in the picture below:

> [image: Blob with tentacles]

I need to find the precise contour so using *dilate/erode* is not ideal.

Comment: Next time please provide a [example] of what you tried. Stackoverflow is no solution-factory but wants to help everyone who struggles with own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cv2.morphologyEx()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#opening) with the morph open operation (`cv2.MORPH_OPEN`) and an elliptical shaped kernel (`cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE`) created with [`cv2.getStructuringElement()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element). This is essentially an erosion followed by a dilation so this operation will remove the noise and keep the spherical shape of the blob. You can experiment with various kernel sizes to remove more or less of the blob and the strength of the operation by changing the number of iterations. Here's the result after performing a morph open:

[image]

From here we find the bounding box coordinates and draw a rectangle around the blob.

[image]

```
import cv2

image = 255 - cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=4)

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(opening)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```